# Which is correct (if any): "please let me know what do you think"? or "please let me know what you think"?

Tags: grammar

I find myself unsure which of the following is more correct:

> please let me know what do you think

Or

> please let me know what you think

My gut feeling tells me that it's the latter...

Or are both incorrect and there is a better way to say the same thing?

Comment: Your gut is wise.  The *do* is implied.

Comment: Maybe the former could be read as *"Please let me know: What do you think?"* In that form I believe it too would be correct.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Please let me know what you think

is correct. Even if *do* were to be included, the correct form would be

> Please let me know what you do think

but this should only be used for emphasis (for example, to contrast with *don't think*).

Answer (score 10):

The latter is correct and the former is definitely wrong.

When you construct questions in English, you follow this pattern: V + S, that's why you have the Helping Verb "Do" there.

But when you construct sentences, it's the opposite, you have to follow: S + V. And if you add any other Noun Clauses or Noun Phrases to your sentence, whether they were originally in question form, they cannot follow the "V + S" question pattern.

Take a look:

What are you thinking? = Question

Please tell me what YOU ARE thinking. = Sentence

Notice that I switched the Verb and the Subject in the original question.

In the same way:

What do you like? = Question

Please tell me what you LIKE. = Sentence

Where did you go? = Question

Please tell me where you WENT.

- "Do" and "Did" as Helping Verbs are normally used only in Questions and Negative sentences, not positive sentences

This topic also encompasses Direct and Indirect Questions

http://www.coolelf.net/2011/12/are-you-direct-or-indirect.html